# Eclipse (c/c++) header files not in download?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

Have never used eclipse, so bear with me. Are header files not part of the standard c/c++ eclipse download? Can't find them anywhere when trying to specify the path for the includes. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: What OS are you running? Also don't forget to download CDT pluggin.

Comment: I think the plug-ins are installed, should the header files be in there?

Comment: To use C or C++ in eclipse you have to get your compiler (and header files) separately. Last time I looked gcc/g++ was the only compiler supported, but things may have moved on since then.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FhkEzinEdI)